# Converting 'uint8_t' 'float' and 'unsigned char' into 'char' for LCD display

Tags: c, avr, atmega

I'm working on AtMega88PA with well-working LCD display.

I've got 2 working methods from the internet:

```
extern void lcd_putc(char c);          // send one 'char' to LCD display e.g. lcd_putc('A')
extern void lcd_puts(const char *s);   // send more chars e.g lcd_puts("something")
```

And those are working great. However if I want to send **uint8_t** LCD is showing weird symbol - 4 horizontal lines.

I've tried to project this integer using:

```
lcd_putc((char) integer);
```

Both outside and inside function, with same result.
I also tried to convert a number from BCD to Decimal and otherwise.
It's same for unsigned char - for some reason when I try to display unsigned char same character appears on LCD display.

How do I convert other data types into char in C?

Comment: How about `snprintf`?

Comment: You should first understand what it means for data to be a "character" versus being number. Really, without this understanding you won't be able to progress to much. From computer perspective both are numbers, and the only difference is how it is interpreted in the specific context.

Comment: If it's a single digit ASCII, try `lcd_putc(integer + '0');`

Comment: @JohnnyMopp, great, that works well with single digit, thanks :)

Comment: @FiddlingBits thanks, this works as well. I think this is a reply to my problem so thanks a lot :)

Comment: @FiddlingBits yes - but it took 2/3 of its FLASH and 2/3 of RAM. This atmega has 1kB SRAM and 8kB of FLASH. If it is not just a few line program it will simple do not have enough resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

snprintf() is the answer!

Thank you all

Answer (score 3):

To convert `unsigned`, `signed`, `float` and `double` on AVR controllers you can use following functions:

**Unsigned 2 ASCII**

```c
unsigned char data = 100;
char buffer[9];

ultoa(data, buffer, base);
```

**Signed 2 ASCII**

```c
signed char data = -10;
char buffer[9];

ltoa(data, buffer, base);
```

The base can be:

- 2 for binary
- 10 for decimal
- 16 for hexadecimal

Buffer size has to be adapted within the width of the number (e.g. for unsigned char 0-255 (decimal) 4 digits are necessary max. number + escape sequence '\0').

**Double 2 ASCII**

```c
double data = 3.14;
char buffer[20];

// Normal form:
dtostrf(data, length, precision, buffer);

// Exponential form:
dtostre(data, buffer, precision, DTOSTR_ALWAYS_SIGN | DTOSTR_UPPERCASE);
```

Parameter of floating point conversion:

- Length is the complete length of the number (e.g. for 3.14 it is 4)
- Precision defines the length to the right of the decimal point

Buffer size has to be adapted within the width of the number

> The functions can be found in `stdlib.h`. There is a sample library [here](https://github.com/ak-app/megacard/blob/master/library/lcd/lcd.c) where they are implemented.

After conversion you can simply call

```c
lcd_puts(buffer);
```

Maybe this helps